# Typing Array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, typing

right now I try to type a parameter which gets an array filled with x amounts of objects:

```
let MScalendar: any = await this.getMSCalendarBeforeToday(currentUser.Id)
```

I tried typing it with an interface:

```
export interface mSCalType {
    start: string,
    end: string
}
```

After changing the MScalendar to

```
let MScalendar: mSCalType[] = await this.getMSCalendarBeforeToday(currentUser.Id)
```

getMSCalendarBeforeToday looks as the following:

```
    async getMSCalendarBeforeToday(userId: number) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const clientId = `${microsoftClientIDforCalendar}`;
        const secret =  `${microsoftSecretforCalendar}`;
        const tenantId = `${microsoftTenantIdforCalendar}`;
        const api_url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${vacationEmailforCalendar}/calendar/events`
        let graphResponse = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, tenantId, { tokenAudience: "https://graph.microsoft.com/" })
        let token = await graphResponse.getToken()
        var options = {
            url: api_url,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.accessToken
            },
        };
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body)
                let myCalendarItems = parsedBody.value.filter(item => +item.bodyPreview == userId)
                myCalendarItems.sort((a,b) => (a.start.dateTime>b.start.dateTime)? 1 : ((b.start.dateTime > a.start.dateTime) ? -1 : 0))
                resolve(myCalendarItems)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I got the following error:
[image: Error]

Greetings,
Leo

Comment: Can you provide the return type for `this.getMSCalendarBeforeToday`?

Comment: @LeoDog896 thanks for the info, I attached the function to the post.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as plain text in the body of your post. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wXKaOW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a return type to `getMSCalendarBeforeToday` for the compiler to now what type the Promise resolves to.

`async getMSCalendarBeforeToday(userId: number): Promise<mSCalType[]>`

Preferably you also add the type after you've parsed the body. Something like

`let parsedBody: { value: mSCalType[] } = JSON.parse(body)`